# How to specify constraint in Meteor Http call?

Tags: meteor

I need to pass a where constraint(where UserName = "User1") in Meteor http call for Parse Rest APIs. Currently, the result that I get after the below API call includes all the entries not just those where UserName is User1.

```
 var authUrl = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ImageData";    
 Meteor.http.call("GET", authUrl, {
            headers: {
                "X-Parse-Application-Id": "2CMX1b4JY5xCOPrYEbSc69ucNDDh9pl5yFeqv3A3",
                "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "9UWpw6H7UuBaOEQgT7R3ANQ3rE67yxZxcMHJJaBu",
                "content-type": "application/json"

            },

            params: {
                "UserName": "User1",
            }

        }, function(error, result) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(result.content));
        }

    );
```

The parse documentation for such an HTTP call in curl representation is:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 2CMX1b4JY5xCOPrYEbSc69ucNDDh9pl5yFeqv3A3" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 9UWpw6H7UuBaOEQgT7R3ANQ3rE67yxZxcMHJJaBu" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"UserName":"User1"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ImageData
```

How can I correctly write this in Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it works:

```js
var util = Npm.require('util');

var url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ImageData';

var result = HTTP.get(url, {
  headers: {
    'X-Parse-Application-Id': '2CMX1b4JY5xCOPrYEbSc69ucNDDh9pl5yFeqv3A3',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': '9UWpw6H7UuBaOEQgT7R3ANQ3rE67yxZxcMHJJaBu',
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  query: 'where={"UserName":"User1"}'
});

console.log(util.inspect(result.data, {depth: null}));
```

#### Notes

- `Meteor.http.call` is deprecated. Use the [HTTP](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call) API instead. Note you will need to `$ meteor add http`.
- Because you need a string and not a key/value pair, use `query` instead of `params`. For a GET, both are placed into the query string but your original code made the query `?Username=User1` rather than `?where...`.

Comment: Thanks David. The problem is solved after I followed the solution that you provided.

Comment: Also, I want to ask, Inside the where query, how can I specify UserName from a variable instead of fixed string.

Comment: if the name of your variable was `username` could do this: `query: 'where={"UserName":' + username + '}'`